# How to add a control after another dynamically?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, location

What i am looking for is how to add another control(say a textbox directly under another textbox) that is added through code rather than the designer.  I can get it to work using the .height property of the control then adding another 10-20 to it

```
dim space as integer
space += textbox1.height + 10
```

however, is there a way to do this on the location rather than the height?  In this case, if I want to add a textbox at the very end of the frame or groupbox without having to add additional in between.  Since the location takes two parameters(x,y), is it possible to place controls based on another controls location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? (not clear what you are after, but yes, you can set the Location or Size all at once):

```
Dim thisTB as new TextBox
thisTB.Location = new Point(xSpot, ySpot)
thisTB.Size =  otherTB.Size
Me.Controls.Add(thisTB)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm looking to place the location of one textbox(such as thisTB) and then place another directly after a different control(say thisTB was in a groupbox and I want to place another textbox after the groupbox, I would just take the location of the groupbox and throw a couple pixels after the groupbox)

Comment: i dont know how to translate "after the groupbox" to a location - below?, to the right?  Inside it?  At anyrate just set the location to the reference control (apparently a group box) to .Left + .Width + myMargin and .Top + .Height + myMargin.

Comment: What would your myMargins value be in the properties?

Comment: thats the couple of pixels you were talking about...depends on how much space you want to leave